# Number of ways to order a collection of objects, when each object can only be in a certain range of positions?

Tags: combinatorics

Let's say we have a series of slots of varying size. Each slot can only fit one object, and only if the object is not larger than the slot. Given an ordered collection of slot sizes, and an unordered collection (with the same number of elements) of object sizes, in how many ways can we order the latter such that for each slot, object size $\leq$ slot size?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let each object be $X_1, X_2, ... X_n$, where $X_i \le X_{i+1}$. Let $Y_i$ be the number of slots in which $X_i$ can fit. Clearly, $Y_i \ge Y_{i+1}$.

Start by putting the largest object in a slot in which it fits. There are $Y_n$ ways to do this. Then put the second largest object in a slot in which it fits. There are $Y_{n-1}-1$ ways to do this. Keep putting the next largest object in a slot. The answer is $$Y_n \prod_{i=1}^{n-1} (Y_{n-i} -i)$$